# How do I re-attach my spacebar key (I took it off)?

Tags: keyboard

I can't work out how to reattach my spacebar properly. I have tried for over an hour and looked for help online but nothing shows the type of spacebar I have with two metal bars the same size.

How do I reattach the metal bars? I've tried to force them under the tabs but they don't seem to fit. There's got to be a technique to do it.

[image: Keyboard with detached spacebar key]
[image]
[image]

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=jgP90sO2AKs#t=403

Comment: Sorry, missed the next / previous links at the top of that image hoster's page! Edited again.

Comment: Agree with @Ramhound I've never successfully reattached a spacebar.

Answer (score 1):

With those kind of butterfly switches, I usually find it easier to carefully pull out the white plastic scissor hinges, attach them onto the corresponding mounting point of the spacebar, then just press the spacebar back into position. you should hear cliking noises as the hinges get back into place.

It looks like the side metal supports are just that - supports. They don't need to be inserted into something.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to align one set (top or bottom) with the respective hooks and hook them on. You then need to get the space bar a little past where it should be, then use something like a toothpick or a paperclip to hook the opposite side. Lift, align and press down the spacebar so that the actual button and its plunger lock in place.

Its finicky, and many keyboards only have one set, but its doable

Answer (score 0):

Aside from it going to be really hard to attach it, its going to be evenly hard to explain how to reattach it, but I'm gonna try anyway.

The two metal bars have to go into the side underneath the keyboard and then turn so it is fixated below it. It should click at that point, but you might need a tool to either rotate the bar or somehow click it once its in position.

Comment: What do you mean into the side underneath?

Comment: The first image did not really show the metal leads well, so it seemed they had to be on the other side. now that you posted the second image with the clearly visible metal T's you have to push it under the T. First one end, then using a screwdriver or something carefully getting the 2nd half in.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with a HP Envy M6.  It took me 3 sleepless nights to figure it out.  I almost ordered a new keyboard until I scrutinized the spacebar itself and noticed that the two long metal clips actually are removable.  This is what I did:

1. Remove both metal clips
2. Attach each metal clip onto the side retainers and open both as if the plastic spacebar is sitting on top
3. Place spacebar on top and press firmly all around.  You should hear a clipping noise and voila, your detached spacebar is fixed.

You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

I removed the metal spring wire and snapped it into the 4 mounts,hooked the wire back in and snapped the button back.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).